# #1045 Cannot log in to the MySQL server

Tags: sql, zend-framework, phpmyadmin

I am on Mac OSX using Zend Studio and suddenly one day I got error #2002, then when I tried to change the settings from localhost to 127.0.0.1 I started to get error #1045.

I looked everywhere for an answer but nothing worked for me. My last hope is to reinstall a fresh copy, but I would like to retrieve my database tables, any idea how can that be done would be much appreciated.

I should mention that the error is given when entering the default user & password 'root' & ''. I tried entering my computers password and it worked, but it's not the same installation as I don't see the tables I was working on.

Answer (score 0):

To be 100% percent sure the problem doesn't came from Zend Studio try to use [Sequel Pro](http://www.sequelpro.com/) to access and backup your database.

Comment: Cannot connect with Sequal either, it times out rather than give access denied.

Comment: how did you setup MySQL ? Through XAMPP ?

Comment: I first installed MAMP Pro, then later I installed Zend Studio. Connection to phpmyadmin through the default port and mamp port work fine, but my tables are of course not there.

Comment: You can connect to the DB but do not found any table ? Did you at least see the database ? Does Zend Studio embed its own version of MySQL

Comment: I believe so yes. When I login through the other ports I see other tables from Mamp, not what I was working on with Zend. Port 10081 was assigned when I installed Zend, I used to connect through it, now I can no longer connect using the 'root' & '', but I can connect through this port using my computers password and root user.

Comment: The error #2002 is supposed to indicate that the server doesn't respond. It might have failed to start, did you try to reboot ? Are you sure there's no other MySQL instance running on the same port.

Comment: It's as if the port 10081 was hijacked by the system and became the default.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15214/discussion-between-aster-and-acidking)